# What is the most efficient C++ method to split a string based on a particular delimiter similar to split method in python?

Tags: c++, string, split

```
getline(cin,s);
istringstream iss(s);
do
{
    string sub;
    iss>>sub;
    q.insert(sub);
 }while(iss);
```

I used this technique when question wanted me to split on the basis of space so can anyone explain me how to split when there's a particular delimiter like ';' or ':'.

Someone told me about strtok function but i am not able to get it's usage so it would be nice if someone could help.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1170333

Comment: The most efficient way is to SEARCH this information at StackOverflow. Thiis has been answered before.

Comment: The most efficient way is to SEARCH this information at Google. (@harper upvoted)

Comment: @vs13 In future before asking a question you might want to be informed [about this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ will keep this in mind.

Comment: I implemented a [delimited input stream iterator](https://gist.github.com/sftrabbit/4335b21717fff8f8932a). To use, fill a `std::istringstream` with your string, then do: `std::vector<std::string> split{delim_istream_iterator<>{ss, ':'}, delim_istream_iterator<>{}};`. Replace `:` with whatever your delimiter is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, don't use `strtok`.  Ever.

There's not really a function for this in the standard library.
I use something like:

```
std::vector<std::string>
split( std::string const& original, char separator )
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string::const_iterator start = original.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = original.end();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::find( start, end, separator );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.push_back( std::string( start, next ) );
        start = next + 1;
        next = std::find( start, end, separator );
    }
    results.push_back( std::string( start, next ) );
    return results;
}
```

I believe Boost has a number of such functions.  (I implemented
most of mine long before there was Boost.)

Comment: Thanks a lot helping I was looking for something like this thanks :)

Comment: @vs13 You may still wan't to accept this answer if it helped you. Click the big white checkmark in the left ...